# If there are no relevant regressors, what will happen to the significance of the regression?

Tags: self-study, econometrics

A researcher who has no idea about the underlying economic theory that determines the dependent variable is trying to “game” the R-squared by using 50 regressors (x1, x2,..., x50). He also adopts a relatively lenient standard of 10% level of significance in conducting t-tests (against a two-sided alternative). Due to his lack of understanding of economic theory, he does not realize that all the 50 regressors are actually irrelevant variables. How many statistically significant regressors do you expect he could obtain in the regression?

So my intuitive answer is none since all the variables are irrelevant. I wonder what you think.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: hint: think about what it means to test for statistical significance at the 10% level, and think about what happens if you do 50 of those tests.

Comment: Please find a different title for your question. It could hardly be less informative for other users of this site.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a question of "what we think" nor of what your intuition says.  Intuition is a notoriously poor tool for solving statistics problems.

Since this is a self-study problem, I won't tell you the answer. But there are two ways to find it:

1. You could simulate the situation a bunch of times and see what happens.
2. You could think about the definition of a p-value and statistical significance.

HINTS: Your intuition is incorrect and solving the problem using the second method involves only simple arithmetic.

Comment: +1 Thank you for posting such a thoughtful and well-motivated answer.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to know is that plain R2 always increase when you add terms to the model; it NEVER decreases. So adding variables can be tempting as based on R2 the model may seem like a better fit; if you are lucky, one some of the variables will add value to R2 by chance, and little by little, if you have 50 variables, something good (not good) will happen with your R2 value.

This can be misleading and that's why we have adjusted R2, which penalizes on each new variable you add, AIC, BIC and other metrics.

Comment: The question is explicitly quantitative: it asks *how many.*  There is a simple answer that depends on the number of variables and chosen level of significance.

Comment: @whuber may you please then answer it?

Comment: @Luis People are giving hints instead of direct answers because this appears to be a study question (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info))

Comment: R2 always increase when you add terms to the model; it NEVER decreases. I doubt that it is a true statement.

Comment: @subhashc.davar this is a true statement and can be mathematically proved.

Comment: mathematical statistics has its own assumptions and some interactios  can not be ruled out. Addition of one or more  variables does not guarantee increase in R squared estimate.

Comment: @subhashc.davar if it does not increase, it stays the same, but will never decrease. Adding 50 new variables has a huge chance of increasing your R2.

Comment: Eating too much daily should cause a health problem and consequently, you may lose your  weight.

Comment: @subhashc.davar From Wikipedia: 
"In all instances where R2 is used, the predictors are calculated by ordinary least-squares regression: that is, by minimizing SSres. In this case R2 increases as we increase the number of variables in the model (R2 is monotone increasing with the number of variables included—i.e., it will never decrease)."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76779/discussion-between-subhash-c-davar-and-luis).